# Why Mysql release_lock() is not releasing lock in multithreaded environment?

Tags: mysql, multithreading

I got a typical problem with mysql locking.
I am running 10 threads in a JVM and trying to acquire lock using mysql `get_lock(stirng)`.
But when those threads comes to release lock, one of them does not release and others get stuck..could not proceed.
What can be cause behind this?

Comment: Code would help us to help you. There are many reasons why this could happen and without code and some output we can just play guessing game.

Comment: ok .. so bellow is my part of code: